# jQuery POST in Codeigniter controller return the same page instead data of another page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm trying to make a POST using jQuery ajax to one controller in Codeigniter, but the POST return success with DATA, and inside the DATA the HTML and PHP code of the page instead of return the line.

When I access the function by URL on the browser, it works and return the line.

**mods.js**

```
$('#maspServidor').on('input', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    console.log("passei por aqui"); 

    var maspServidor = $('#maspServidor').val();
    if (maspServidor.length >= 3){
        $.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo base_url() ?>Control_mods/servidoresJSON", 
            data: {
                'operacao': 'buscarPorMasp'
            },
            success: function(data){
                console.log("DATA -> "+data)
            },
            error: function(error){
                console.log("ERROR -> "+error)
            },
            type: "POST"
        });
    }
});
```

**mods.php**

```
<?php echo validation_errors(); ?> 
<?php echo form_open('', $form_attr); ?>
<section class="panel panel-default padding_pequeno" id="dados_servidor">
    <div class="panel-heading text-center">Dados do Servidor</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="form-group" id="campoMaspServidor">
                <label class="control-label" for="maspServidor">Masp</label>            
                <input class="form-control" type="number" min="99999" name="maspServidor" value="<?php echo set_value('maspServidor'); ?>" id="maspServidor" aria-describedby="maspServidor">
            </div>
        ...
        ...
        ...
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

**Control_mods.php**

```
public function servidoresJSON(){
    echo json_encode($this->Servidores_crud->servidoresPorMasp());
}
```

**Servidores_crud.php**

```
public function servidoresPorMasp(){
    return $this->db->select('maspServidor')
    ->select('nomeServidor')
    ->like('maspServidor', '135') // this values is static just for tests
    ->get('servidores')
    ->result_array();
}
```

**response**

```
DATA -> 


<div style="border:1px solid #990000;padding-left:20px;margin:0 0 10px 0;">

<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>

<p>Severity: Warning</p>
<p>Message:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach()</p>
<p>Filename: controllers/Control_mods.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 85</p>


<p>Backtrace:</p>






        <p style="margin-left:10px">
        File:          
 C:\xampp\htdocs\MinutaOnline\application\controllers\Control_mods.php<br />
        Line: 85<br />
        Function: _error_handler            </p>






        <p style="margin-left:10px">
        File: C:\xampp\htdocs\MinutaOnline\index.php<br />
        Line: 315<br />
        Function: require_once          </p>




</div><link     
href="http://localhost/MinutaOnline/assets/css/vendor/bootstrap.min.css"  
rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="http://localhost/MinutaOnline/assets/css/vendor/ie10-viewport-  
bug-workaround.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="http://localhost/MinutaOnline/assets/css/general.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="http://localhost/MinutaOnline/assets/js/vendor/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://localhost/MinutaOnline/assets/js/vendor/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <div class="container">
   <!-- Static navbar -->
   <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://localhost/MinutaOnline/Control_login/menu">MinutaOnline</a>
      </div>
      <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse" aria-expanded="false" style="height: 1px;">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Minutas<span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">

              <li>
                <a href="http://localhost/MinutaOnline/Control_mods/index/1">
                  Mod. 03 F�RIAS-PR�MIO/ CONCESS�O 
                </a>
              </li>

              <li>
                <a href="http://localhost/MinutaOnline/Control_mods/index/2">
                  Mod 04
                </a>
              </li>

            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Minha Conta <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="http://localhost/MinutaOnline/Control_login/logout">Sair</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div><!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link href="http://localhost/MinutaOnline/assets/css/mods.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="http://localhost/MinutaOnline/assets/js/mods.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        json = '{"1":[{"idLotacao":"1","lotacao":"E.E. Jos\ufffd Ac\ufffdcio da Silva"}],"2":[{"idLotacao":"2","lotacao":"E.E. Armando Santos"},{"idLotacao":"3","lotacao":"E.E. Cel. Jos\ufffd Adolfo de Aguiar"},{"idLotacao":"4","lotacao":"E.E. Delfim Moreira"},{"idLotacao":"5","lotacao":"E.E. Dom Jos\ufffd Gaspar"},{"idLotacao":"6","lotacao":"E.E. Dr. Eduardo Montandon"},{"idLotacao":"7","lotacao":"E.E. Lia Salgado"},{"idLotacao":"8","lotacao":"E.E. Loren Rios Feres"},{"idLotacao":"9","lotacao":"E.E. Luiza de Oliveira Faria"},{"idLotacao":"10","lotacao":"E.E. Maria de Magalh\ufffdes"},{"idLotacao":"11","lotacao":"E.E. Padre Anacleto Giraldi"},{"idLotacao":"12","lotacao":"E.E. Padre Jo\ufffdo Botelho"},{"idLotacao":"13","lotacao":"E.E. Pio XII"},{"idLotacao":"14","lotacao":"E.E. Prof. Lu\ufffds Ant\ufffdnio Corr\ufffda de Oliveira"},{"idLotacao":"15","lotacao":"E.E. Rotary"},{"idLotacao":"16","lotacao":"E.E. Vasco Santos"}],"3":[{"idLotacao":"17","lotacao":"E.E. Padre Henrique Peeters"}],"4":[{"idLotacao":"18","lotacao":"E.E. Deir\ufffd Borges"},{"idLotacao":"19","lotacao":"E.E. Dr. Jos\ufffd Cordeiro de Campos"},{"idLotacao":"20","lotacao":"E.E. Padre Clemente de Maleto"}],"5":[{"idLotacao":"21","lotacao":"E.E. Bom Sucesso"}],"6":[{"idLotacao":"22","lotacao":"E.E. Marechal Hermes"}],"7":[{"idLotacao":"23","lotacao":"E.E. Comendador Gomes"}],"8":[{"idLotacao":"24","lotacao":"E.E. Hercul\ufffdrgio Ant\ufffdnio Borges"},{"idLotacao":"25","lotacao":"E.E. Jos\ufffd Alexandre Miziara"}],"9":[{"idLotacao":"26","lotacao":"E.E. Dr Lindolfo Bernardes"}],"10":[{"idLotacao":"27","lotacao":"E.E. Ivan Mattar Soukef"}],"11":[{"idLotacao":"28","lotacao":"E.E. Ensino Fundamental"},{"idLotacao":"29","lotacao":"E.E. Jo\ufffdo Kopke"}],"12":[{"idLotacao":"35","lotacao":"E.E. Presidente Tancredo Neves"}],"13":[{"idLotacao":"30","lotacao":"E.E. Geralda Carvalho de Souza"},{"idLotacao":"31","lotacao":"E.E. Lauriston Souza"},{"idLotacao":"32","lotacao":"E.E. Maestro Josino de Oliveira"},{"idLotacao":"33","lotacao":"E.E. Professor Bandeira"},{"idLotacao":"34","lotacao":"E.E. Vicente de Macedo"}],"14":[{"idLotacao":"36","lotacao":"E.E. Alonso de Morais Andrade"},{"idLotacao":"37","lotacao":"E.E. Santo Ant\ufffdnio"},{"idLotacao":"38","lotacao":"E.E. Serra da Moeda"}],"15":[{"idLotacao":"39","lotacao":"E.E. Dom Alexandre"}],"16":[{"idLotacao":"40","lotacao":"E.E. Ant\ufffdnio Ferreira Barbosa"},{"idLotacao":"41","lotacao":"E.E. Joaquim Tiago de Queiroz"},{"idLotacao":"42","lotacao":"E.E. Nossa Senhora de Lourdes"},{"idLotacao":"43","lotacao":"E.E. Tiradentes"}],"17":[{"idLotacao":"44","lotacao":"E.E. Izoldino Soares de Freitas"}],"18":[{"idLotacao":"45","lotacao":"E.E. Professor Le\ufffdo Coelho de Almeida"}],"19":[{"idLotacao":"46","lotacao":"E.E. Coronel Oscar de Castro"}],"20":[{"idLotacao":"47","lotacao":"E.E. Alysson Roberto Bruno"}],"21":[{"idLotacao":"48","lotacao":"E.E. Marlene Martins Reis"}],"22":[{"idLotacao":"49","lotacao":"E.E. Bar\ufffdo da Rifania"},{"idLotacao":"50","lotacao":"E.E. Coronel Jos\ufffd Afonso de Almeida"},{"idLotacao":"51","lotacao":"E.E. de Ensino M\ufffddio"},{"idLotacao":"52","lotacao":"E.E. Dr. Jos\ufffd Afonso Pena J\ufffdnior"},{"idLotacao":"53","lotacao":"E.E. Sinhana Borges"}],"23":[{"idLotacao":"54","lotacao":"E.E. S\ufffdo Francisco de Sales"}],"24":[{"idLotacao":"55","lotacao":"E.E. Santa Juliana"}],"25":[{"idLotacao":"56","lotacao":"E.E. Prof\ufffd Cecilia M\ufffd de Resende Neves"}],"26":[{"idLotacao":"57","lotacao":"E.E. Am\ufffdrica"},{"idLotacao":"58","lotacao":"E.E. Anexa a Supam"},{"idLotacao":"59","lotacao":"E.E. Aur\ufffdlio Luiz da Costa"},{"idLotacao":"60","lotacao":"E.E. Bernardo Vasconcelos"},{"idLotacao":"61","lotacao":"E.E. Boulanger Pucci"},{"idLotacao":"62","lotacao":"E.E. Brasil"},{"idLotacao":"63","lotacao":"E.E. Carmelita Carvalho Garcia"},{"idLotacao":"64","lotacao":"CESEC"},{"idLotacao":"65","lotacao":"CEOPEE - Centro de Orienta\ufffd\ufffdo e Pesquisa em Educa\ufffd\ufffdo Especial"},{"idLotacao":"66","lotacao":"CIEL"},{"idLotacao":"67","lotacao":"C.E.M. Renato Frateschi"},{"idLotacao":"68","lotacao":"E.E. Dom Eduardo"},{"idLotacao":"69","lotacao":"E.E. Dr Jos\ufffd Mendon\ufffda"},{"idLotacao":"70","lotacao":"E.E. Prof. Minervino Cesarino"},{"idLotacao":"71","lotacao":"E.E. Fel\ufffdcio de Paiva"},{"idLotacao":"72","lotacao":"E.E. Fid\ufffdlis Reis"},{"idLotacao":"73","lotacao":"E.E. Frei Leopoldo de Castelnuovo"},{"idLotacao":"74","lotacao":"E.E. Gabriel Toti"},{"idLotacao":"75","lotacao":"E.E. Geraldino Rodrigues da Cunha"},{"idLotacao":"76","lotacao":"E.E. Henrique Kr\ufffdger"},{"idLotacao":"77","lotacao":"E.E. Horizonta Lemos"},{"idLotacao":"78","lotacao":"E.E. Irm\ufffdo Afonso"},{"idLotacao":"79","lotacao":"E.E. Lauro Fontoura"},{"idLotacao":"80","lotacao":"E.E. Leandro Ant\ufffdnio de Vito"},{"idLotacao":"81","lotacao":"E.E. Mal. Humberto de Alencar Castelo Branco"},{"idLotacao":"82","lotacao":"E.E. Miguel Laterza"},{"idLotacao":"83","lotacao":"E.E. Minas Gerais"},{"idLotacao":"84","lotacao":"E.E. Nossa Senhora da Abadia"},{"idLotacao":"85","lotacao":"E.E. Paulo Jos\ufffd Derenusson"},{"idLotacao":"86","lotacao":"E.E. Presidente Jo\ufffdo Pinheiro"},{"idLotacao":"87","lotacao":"E.E. Professor Alceu Novaes"},{"idLotacao":"88","lotacao":"E.E. Professor Chaves"},{"idLotacao":"89","lotacao":"E.E. Professor Hildebrando Pontes"},{"idLotacao":"90","lotacao":"E.E. Professora Corina de Oliveira"},{"idLotacao":"91","lotacao":"E.E. Quintiliano Jardim"},{"idLotacao":"92","lotacao":"E.E. Rotary"},{"idLotacao":"93","lotacao":"E.E. Santa Terezinha"},{"idLotacao":"94","lotacao":"E.E. S\ufffdo Benedito"},{"idLotacao":"95","lotacao":"E.E. Alo\ufffdzio Castanheira"},{"idLotacao":"96","lotacao":"E.E. Prof\ufffd Neide de Oliveira Gomes"},{"idLotacao":"97","lotacao":"E.E. Francisco C\ufffdndido Xavier"},{"idLotacao":"98","lotacao":"39\ufffd S R E - UBERABA"}],"27":[{"idLotacao":"99","lotacao":"E.E. Geraldino Rodrigues da Cunha"}],"28":[{"idLotacao":"100","lotacao":"E.E. Dom Pedro II"}],"29":[{"idLotacao":"101","lotacao":"E.E. Prof. Ant\ufffdnio da Silva"}]}';
    </script>

</head>
<body>

    <section class="container" id="cabecalho">
        <div class="panel panel-default padding_pequeno">
            <div class="">
                <p class="text-justify">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 brasao">
                        <img src="http://localhost/MinutaOnline/assets/images/brasao.png" alt="Brasão do Estado de Minas Gerais" class="brasao" />                  </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10">
                        SECRETARIA DE ESTADO DE EDUCAÇÃO<br>
                        SUBSECRETARIA DE GESTÃO DE RECURSOS HUMANOS<br>
                        SUPERINTENDÊNCIA DE NORMAS E INFORMAÇÕES DE PESSOAL<br>
                        DIRETORIA DE LEGISLAÇÕES E NORMAS DE PESSOAL
                    </div>
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <br>
                <p class="text-justify"><b> 

                </b></p>
                <div>
                    <p class="padding_pequeno">
                        SECRETARIA DE ESTADO DE EDUCAÇÃO<br>
                        <span>SUPERINTEND�NCIA DE ENSINO DE UBERABA</span><br>
                        DIRETOR (A): <span>MARILDA RIBEIRO RESENDE</span><br>
                    </p>
                    <p class="text-justify">

                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section class="container" id="minuta">
        <p><script type='text/javascript'>
                        window.onload = campoInvalido('campoMaspServidor','maspServidor','MASP inserido inválido');
                    </script></p>
<p><script type='text/javascript'>
                        window.onload = campoInvalido('campoNomeServidor','nomeServidor','Por favor digite o nome do servidor');
                    </script></p>

        <form action="http://localhost/MinutaOnline/index.php/Control_mods/index/%3C" class="form-horizontal" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
        <section class="panel panel-default padding_pequeno" id="dados_servidor">
            <div class="panel-heading text-center">Dados do Servidor</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="form-group" id="campoMaspServidor">
                    <label class="control-label" for="maspServidor">Masp</label>            
                    <input class="form-control" type="number" min="99999" name="maspServidor" value="" id="maspServidor" aria-describedby="maspServidor">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="admissao">Admissão</label>
                    <select class="form-control" id="admissao" name="admissao" value="">
                        <option value="1" >01</option>
                        <option value="2" >02</option>
                        <option value="3" >03</option>
                        <option value="4" >04</option>
                        <option value="5" >05</option>
                    </select>                   
                </div>

                idCargo                 idNivel                 idGrau              <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="cargo">Cargo</label>

                    <select class="inline form-control" id="idCargo" name="idCargo" value="">

                        <option value="1" >PEB</option>

                        <option value="2" >ASB</option>

                        <option value="3" >ATB</option>

                        <option value="4" >EEB</option>

                        <option value="5" >TDE</option>

                        <option value="6" >ANE</option>

                        <option value="7" >ANEI</option>

                        <option value="8" >AEB</option>

                        <option value="9" >ASE</option>

                    </select>

                    <select class="inline form-control" id="idNivel" name="idNivel" value="">

                        <option value="1" >1 / I</option>

                        <option value="2" >2 / II</option>

                        <option value="3" >3 / III</option>

                        <option value="4" >4 /IV</option>

                        <option value="5" >5 / V</option>

                    </select>

                    <select class="inline form-control" id="idGrau" name="idGrau" value="">

                        <option value="1" >A</option>

                        <option value="2" >B</option>

                        <option value="3" >C</option>

                        <option value="4" >D</option>

                        <option value="5" >E</option>

                        <option value="6" >F</option>

                        <option value="7" >G</option>

                        <option value="8" >H</option>

                        <option value="9" >I</option>

                        <option value="10" >J</option>

                        <option value="11" >L</option>

                        <option value="12" >M</option>

                        <option value="13" >N</option>

                        <option value="14" >O</option>

                        <option value="15" >P</option>

                    </select>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group" id="campoNomeServidor">
                    <!-- Quebrar linha -->          
                    <label class="control-label" for="nomeServidor">
                        Nome do Servidor
                    </label>
                    <input class="form-control" name="nomeServidor" value="" id="nomeServidor" aria-describedby="nomeServidor"/>
                </div>
                <!-- Quebrar linha -->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="localidade" class="control-label" for="localidade">
                        Localidade
                    </label>                                    
                    <select class="form-control" id="localidade" name="localidade" value="">

                        <option value="1" >Água Comprida</option>

                        <option value="2" >Araxá</option>

                        <option value="3" >Campo Florido</option>

                        <option value="4" >Campos Altos</option>

                        <option value="5" >Carneirinho (Estrela da Barra)</option>

                        <option value="6" >Carneirinho</option>

                        <option value="7" >Comendador Gomes</option>

                        <option value="8" >Concei��o das Alagoas</option>

                        <option value="9" >Conquista</option>

                        <option value="10" >Delta</option>

                        <option value="11" >Fronteira</option>

                        <option value="12" >Frutal (Distrito Aparecida de Minas)</option>

                        <option value="13" >Frutal</option>

                        <option value="14" >Itapagipe</option>

                        <option value="15" >Iturama Distrito de Alexandrita</option>

                        <option value="16" >Iturama</option>

                        <option value="17" >Limeira do Oeste</option>

                        <option value="18" >Pedrin�polis</option>

                        <option value="19" >Pirajuba</option>

                        <option value="20" >Planura</option>

                        <option value="21" >Pratinha</option>

                        <option value="22" >Sacramento</option>

                        <option value="23" >Santa Juliana</option>

                        <option value="24" >São Francisco de Sales</option>

                        <option value="25" >Tapira</option>

                        <option value="26" >Uberaba</option>

                        <option value="27" >Uni�o de Minas</option>

                        <option value="28" >Verissimo</option>

                        <option value="29" >Carneirinho (São Sebastião do Pontal)</option>

                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <!-- Quebrar linha -->  
                    <label class="control-label" for="idLotacao">
                        Órgão de lotação/exercício
                    </label>
                    <select class="form-control" name="idLotacao" id="idLotacao">
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section class="panel panel-default padding_pequeno" id="dados_minuta" >
            <div class="panel-heading text-center">Dados da Publicação</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="form-group" id="campoPublicarApartir">
                    <label class="control-label" for="publicarApartir">Publicar a partir de:</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="date" name="publicarApartir" id="publicarApartir" value="2016-11-15" aria-describedby="publicarApartir">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group" id="campo{htmlId}">
                    <label class="control-label" for="{htmlName}">
                        {label}
                    </label>
                    <{htmlTag} class="{htmlClass}" id="{htmlId}" name="{htmlName}" value="" aria-describedby="{htmlId}" {htmlAttributes}>
                </div>                  
                {/camposMinuta}
            </section>
            <section class="panel panel-default padding_pequeno" id="dados_minuta">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="alinha_inicio col-xs-4 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
                            <button type="button"  name="voltar" id="voltar" class="btn btn-warning">Voltar</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="alinha_centro col-xs-4 col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-2 col-md-offset-3 col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-3">
                            <button type="button"  name="limpar" id="limpar" class="btn btn-default">Limpar</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="alinha_final col-xs-4 col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-2 col-md-offset-3 col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-3">
                            <button type="submit" id="protocolar" class="btn btn-primary">Protocolar</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>

            <div class="container">
                <p class="text-justify">

                </p>
            </div> 


            </form>         <footer>
                <h6>
                    <p class="text-center">
                        <small>
                            Powered by Nerd Dash - 2016
                        </small>                        
                    </p>
                </h6>
            </footer> 
        </section>

    </body>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function(){
            console.log("idCargo -> "+document.getElementById('idCargo').value);
        };
    </script>

    </html>
```

Comment: any errors in console? can you post the rendered page containing that js snippet?

Comment: I have the feeling I've seen this exact question multiple times here already

Comment: Have you tried the proposed solutions in these questions?

Comment: No errors in console :( , and about the solutions nothing specific about my error.

Comment: Sorry for my little english.

Comment: Can you show us the response ?

Comment: The response is the HTML and PHP code of the same page.

Comment: In your controller `Control_mods.php` try to echo hard-coded values. `return json_encode(array('status'=>true))`

Comment: I can't put the response code here because it has more than 18 thousand caracters.

Comment: I put the response in the question.

Comment: Have you seen the response of your php code? Your php code has errors!

Comment: Yes, but it was not to be returning the same page, it was actually to be returning the affected row from the table. Because I make a POST to one controller, the controller access the model and the model access the database and return one line.

Comment: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() is usually a database query problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery post returning rendered html page rather than sql result](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23128416/jquery-post-returning-rendered-html-page-rather-than-sql-result)

Comment: Thanks @empiric, I'll see this.